# If / Or formula not giving the correct True or False statement

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have an If formula as part of my macro code which doesn't seem to be working in the correct manner.

The below code calculates the rCell.Offset and always applies it as being True, I have had examples where it equals 112, 113, 118 etc and it is populating the desired cell as Option 2.

```
If rCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "101" Or "102" Then
        rCell.Value = "Option 2"
        Else
        rCell.Value = "Option 1"
        End If
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb and say that the numbers in rCell.Offset(0, -2) are actual numbers and not text-that-looks-like-a-number. Remember that `101 <> "101"` so remove the quotes as well as correct the Or syntax.

```
If rCell.Offset(0, -2).Value2 = 101 Or rCell.Offset(0, -2).Value2 = 102 Then
    rCell.Value = "Option 2"
Else
    rCell.Value = "Option 1"
End If
```

Another option would be a [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx).

```
Select Case rCell.Offset(0, -2).Value2
    Case 101, 102
        rCell.Value = "Option 2"
    Case 112, 113
        'do something for these
    Case 118
        'do something for this
    Case Else
        'when nothing else matches
        rCell.Value = "Option 1"
End Select
```

The benefits to this style of condition evaluation becomes quickly apparent when there are several conditions to check.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Try this

```
If rCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "101" Or rCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "102" Then
```

EDIT: Essentially your code is asking

```
If "102"
```

which will always return true.

Comment: I knew it was something simple my mind was blank, thanks alot.